# Convert existing value from one type to another during EntityFramework migration?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have:

```
    [Required]
    public string Proportion { get; set; }
```

which is a string property. I have to apply some simple logic to convert it to the integer. 
**So my goal is to 1) save existing proportions, 2) drop string-column and create new int column with saved and converted to int values instead.** Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your intention correctly, you could delete your `Proportion` entity from the model than migrate your database with `update-database -force` which will delete the column from your db. than re-create the `Proportion` entity to `int` and migrate the db again.

Now you will have the Model and db to be corresponding to `int` type for the `Proportion` entity. Of course, you will have to use another variable to store the string value and than to parse it to `int` and store it to `Proportion`.

In your question you talk about value**s** in plural. In my answer I referred to `int` property which get only one integer. If you have some thing like width*height i would suggest parsing into two separate properties.

Comment: My goal is to save existing data. I know that it is possible to use `int.Parse(...)`, but it does not look like a nice solution. If I do it your way, I will loose all the data.